# Should I have a transit visa in Frankfurt?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, transit, fra

I  have Syrian passport with USA visa. I will travel from USA to Lebanon but I have one stop in Frankfurt. I want to ask if I need visa to stay in the airport in Frankfurt until I have my next flight.

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** require a transit visa.  Reviewing [Germany's visa information](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) shows Syria as a nationality that requires possession of an airport transit visa when passing through the international transit area of airports in Germany, but also that since you hold a valid visa for the United States you are exempt from that requirement (item 1 in the exceptions).